# Trying to figure out K&R C ex 1-22

Tags: c

Noob here again. I am trying to answer chapter 1's 22th exercise and I think I am stuck.

The exercise is to creatively fold a long line after the last non-blank character, but what I have done is eating some characters in the string.

Heres my code:

```
int folder(char line[], int limit)
{
    int count = 0;
    int c, a, mod_a;
    mod_a = 0;
    a = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && count < limit - 1)
    {
        ++a;
        mod_a = a % LINEBREAK;

        switch(mod_a){
            case 0:
                while(a >= count - LINEBREAK + 1)
                {
                    --a;
                    if(line[a] == ' ' || line[a] == '\t')
                    {
                        line[a] = '\n';
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                a = count;
                break;
            default:
                line[count] = c;
                break;
        }
        ++count;
    }

    line[count + 1] = '\0';

    printf("\"");
    for(int each = 0; each < count; ++each)
        printf("%c", line[each]);
    printf("\"");
    printf("\n");

    return count; 
}
```

When I choose LINEBREAK = 5, I get the following:

```
./ex1-22
this is a line
"thiss
a
ine"
```

I dont understand what is happening to the missing characters.
Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can see that you have a lot of superfluous code? Like `continue` in the `else` branch, what else would the loop do? It will go to the next iteration regardless of the `continue`, and the `switch` statement is simply `if (mod_a % LINEBREAK == 0) {} else {}`!!!

Comment: The missing characters are zero; if you initialize "line" to "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...", you'll get the output:
"thisXXs{newline}a{newline}Xline " (excuse the formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `line[count]` for every value of count. Your code doesn't set `line[count]` when `a % LINEBREAK == 0`.